# How to handle concurrency (status 409) errors using HttpContent in ASP.NET MVC Web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working on a Core 3.1 Web API and an MVC application that uses it. In the MVC app I have UserRepo set up containing an `Update` method:

```
public async Task<User> Update(User user)
{
    HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("namedClient");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync($"api/Users/{user.Id}", ContentEncoder.Encode(user));
    try
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if ((int)response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status409Conflict)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<User>();
}
```

The repo is injected into a service, and the service is injected into a controller which is where I'd like to handle the error.

The `Update` method is incomplete because I am trying to figure out how handle a 409 error which I return  from API if the rowversion value was outdated. When `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` is called, an exception is thrown if it wasn't a success code. I imagined I could just have it bubble-up to the front-end and handle it in the controller action, but the exception object doesn't contain anything specific enough to identify that it's a 409 error:
[image]

So if this bubbles up to the controller action, best I could to is try to parse out the status code from the `message`, which seems like a bad idea.

I can find examples of people returning 409 codes from their Web APIs, but not how they would be handled in an MVC app when logic is separated into different classes instead of being all in one action.

How could I handle this? Do I create a custom exception and throw that? Maybe add additional data to the exception with `ex.Data.Add()` and read it in the action? Would that be a bad idea?

Comment: Catch it as `HttpRequestException` instead of general `Exception`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception.statuscode

Comment: @Leandro Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it but the exception object looks identical to that of `Exception`. I don't see a separate `StatusCode` property.

Comment: I'm seeing now that the `StatusCode` property was introduced in Core 5.0. I'm on 3.1.

Comment: I see. Another option would be to create your own custom exception.

Comment: I might end up doing something like that then if no one else suggests anything more because I just can't find a good way of handling it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Instead of calling `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` (which throws exception if the statusCode is different than 2xx) please check the `StatusCode` directly on your `response` object. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65739532/13268855) I've showed a general approach how to prepare your code for unsuccessful responses.

Comment: If you are expecting to handle a particular status code (409) from the API then I would check for it specifically in the update method. Expecting something means it's not really an exception at this point during the execution. You could call `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` later if required. Personally I would probably also create a custom exception and throw that if the code is 409. Then in the layer above I can catch that easily, otherwise handle any other error thrown separately.

Comment: you could see the status code if instead of EnsureSuccessStatusCode you use the response object which contains StatusCode property. Then you wouldnt even need that try catch. Just do something like: if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode) { handle error.... }

Comment: @PeterCsala and @Craig H, thank you for those suggestions. I will be looking at them when I'm back working on this. @Filipe, that's a good point. Are you suggesting something like `if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode && StatusCode == 409) { throw new CustomException }`? Since I do need it to bubble up all the way to the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to suggestions from @Peter Csala, @Craig H, and @Filipe, this is the solution I settled on.

Method that calls the API:

```
public async Task<User> Update(User user)
{
    HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("namedClient");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync($"api/Users/{user.Id}", ContentEncoder.Encode(user));
    await HttpResponseValidator.ValidateStatusCode(response);

    return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<User>();
}
```

A static method I can reuse that will produce an exception during a concurrency error:

```
public static class HttpResponseValidator
{
    public static async Task ValidateStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        if ((int)response.StatusCode < 200 || (int)response.StatusCode > 299)
        {
            string errorResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
            {
                DBConcurrencyException ex = new DBConcurrencyException(errorResponse);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception bubbles up all the way back to the action that called the method calling the API. I catch it in the action and handle it after logging the error.